# Can't figure out how to access Dice.com's REST API

Tags: node.js, api, rest

So I want to use Dice.com's API to grab data for an infographic type application.

http://www.dice.com/common/content/documentation/api.html

My problem is they require a Developer ID and password. I'm not sure where I can get this since it's required for the OAuth token.

I plan on using Node.js to make requests to their RESTful service. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed dicemedia@dice.com (email grabbed from http://www.programmableweb.com/api/dice-jobs) and got a reply:

---

```
Thanks for your interest in the Dice API! It's currently not available 
for public use.  We've been field testing it at some events and hope 
to open it up by the end of Q2 2015.

We'll definitely make an announcement when it opens up.

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Thanks!
```

Comment: Do you know if this has opened up yet? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

I found it pretty easy to get started hacking around with this using Postman (actually for searches you could just start in a browser, with a  JSON plugin installed or the like).

http://www.dice.com/common/content/util/apidoc/jobsearch.html